# R: Replace string when partial match to another column by row

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to replace/remove those parts of a string (`name`) that match to other columns (`state`and `city`) in my data table.

I managed to identify the rows, e.g. with city, like so:
`dt%>% filter(str_detect(name, city))` but I am missing a way to use `gsub` (or `grep`) with the rowwise value of the column city.

I know that a rather manual approach like storing all city names in a vector and enter them in `gsub` would work but it would also falsely remove the "dallas" of row 2. (This was manageable for states though and could be combined with gsub to also remove "of".)

---

**Data and desired output**

```
dt<- data.table(city = c("arecibo","arecibo","cabo rojo", "new york", "dallas"), 
state=c("pr", "pr", "pr", "ny", "tx"), 
name=c("frutas of pr arecibo", "dallas frutas of pr", "cabo rojo metal plant", "greens new york", "cowboy shoes dallas tx"), 
desired=c("frutas", "dallas frutas", "metal plant", "greens", "cowboy shoes"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
# Helper function
subxy <-  function(string, rmv) mapply(function(x, y) sub(x, '', y), rmv, string)

dt[,  desired2 := name |> subxy(city) |> subxy(state) |> subxy('of') |> trimws()]

#         city state                   name       desired      desired2
# 1:   arecibo    pr   frutas of pr arecibo        frutas        frutas
# 2:   arecibo    pr    dallas frutas of pr dallas frutas dallas frutas
# 3: cabo rojo    pr  cabo rojo metal plant   metal plant   metal plant
# 4:  new york    ny        greens new york        greens        greens
# 5:    dallas    tx cowboy shoes dallas tx  cowboy shoes  cowboy shoes
```

Comment: @Magasinus you are using an old version of R but to mitigate you can replace `\(x, y)` with `function(x,y)`

Comment: and `|>` with the magrittr pipe `%>%`.

Comment: This solution is great but has the same issue when applied to real data: it also cleans real names that start with the state abbreviation. Is there a more elegant way to account for this than: `subxy <-  function(string, rmv) mapply(function(x, y) sub(paste(" ",x," ",sep=""), '', paste(" ",y," ",sep="")), rmv, string)` and does this really do the job?

Comment: @Magasinus You can take that into account by requiring space before the statename, simply feeding `subxy()` with `paste0(' ', state)`.

Answer (score 3):

With dplyr, we can use `rowwise`. First collapse all words to remove into a single character element with the OR metacharacter (as in `'arecibo|pr|of'`), then call `str_remove_all` with that pattern.
Finally, remove remaining whitespaces.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dt %>%
    rowwise()%>%
    mutate(desired_2 = str_remove_all(name, paste(c(city, state, 'of'), collapse = '|'))%>%
               trimws())

# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Rowwise: 
  city      state name                   desired       desired_2    
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>                  <chr>         <chr>        
1 arecibo   pr    frutas of pr arecibo   frutas        frutas       
2 arecibo   pr    dallas frutas of pr    dallas frutas dallas frutas
3 cabo rojo pr    cabo rojo metal plant  metal plant   metal plant  
4 new york  ny    greens new york        greens        greens       
5 dallas    tx    cowboy shoes dallas tx cowboy shoes  cowboy shoes
```

Comment: Sorry, we have to use `rowwise` to achieve that, which I used originally, but eventually removed. It is ok now. Please test the updated answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, but it can probably be achieved faster with `gsub` methods. Anyway :

```
library(tidyverse)


  dt %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(name,city)) %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(test,paste(" of ",state,sep=""))) %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(test,state)) %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(test,"^ ")) %>% 
  mutate(test = str_remove_all(test," *$"))
```

Output:

```
        city state                   name       desired          test
1:   arecibo    pr   frutas of pr arecibo        frutas        frutas
2:   arecibo    pr    dallas frutas of pr dallas frutas dallas frutas
3: cabo rojo    pr  cabo rojo metal plant   metal plant   metal plant
4:  new york    ny        greens new york        greens        greens
5:    dallas    tx cowboy shoes dallas tx  cowboy shoes  cowboy shoes
```

Comment: Can we combine this to replace "of" only when followed by a space and `state`?

Comment: Sure, see the edit @Magasinus

Comment: With real data, we have to be careful given states like "ma". It might be advisable to use `mutate(test = str_remove_all(test,paste(" ",state," ", sep=""))`.